# How to provide custom JSON format using Newtonsoft

Tags: asp.net, json, linq, json.net

I use Newtonsoft library to converting LINQ result to JSON format.

The generated JSON is something like following:

```
[{"title":"Some title", "Score":1000}, {"title":"Some title", "Score":2000}]
```

How I can change the result to:

```
 [["Some title", 1000], ["Some title", 2000]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Newtonsoft, but the result you are wanting is not JSON.  JSON is either a "key":"value" pair or a "key":"array of strings". I hope that helps...

Comment: I validated the result, and I found that is a valid JSON format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply return the corresponding object types from your linq expression.

To your LINQ query, add this transformation:

```
var myNewQuery = myQuery.Select( x => new ArrayList{ x.title, x.Score } );
```

then serialize it.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Qj5Ac)

Little bit of explanation: your desired output is an array of arrays, with each inner array having exactly two elements, but of different type. C# generic lists do not allow for that, but you can always use `List<object>` or simply the untyped `ArrayList` for the inner array. Then just let Json.NET do it's thing and serialize all collections (typed or untyped) to [...].

It may also be noteworthy that the answer with the custom `JsonConverter` probably has better performance, in case you have extremely high throughput I'd recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

You must create your own JsonConverter and override the WriteJson method with **some valid json logic** at your pleasure.

```
public class SomeJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

        JObject result = new JObject();
        SomeModel model = (SomeModel)value;
        //create result as you want
        //get JToken.FromObject(model.property) - if you want to get some property from model
        result.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

And you'll use that like this:

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializableModel, Formatting.None, new SomeJsonConverter()));
 //serializableModel has SomeModel type
```

You can check validity for your json here : http://jsonlint.com/

You must store something like:

```
  [
    {
        "Some title": "1000"
    },
    {
        "Some title": "2000"
    }
]
```

If by changing {} to [] you mean create another kind of object you must see this:

A json object looks like this:

```
  {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have an array of objects :

```
[
    {
        "item": "Xylophone"
    },
    {
        "item": "Carrot"
    },
    {
        "item": "Apple"
    }
]
```

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't test your code yet, but I think that will work, could you please tell me, how I can change `{}` to `[]`?

Comment: If this helped you, you can accept the answer. I don't know what you want to accomplish by changing {} to []. Please tell me what you want to do.

Comment: If I got success with your code, I'll check your answer, as answer for sure. I using a jquery plugin and should pass JSON with that format for getting the plugin work.